# Should a UIViewController control a UIView's animations?

Tags: ios, objective-c, model-view-controller, animation, uiview

I've been pushing myself to learn more MVCS styled programming and am attempting to organize my code better. My main question, is I have a UIViewController that brings up a view when an event occurs. When the view is created and when the view is destroyed, I'd like to run some animations on the view appearing and disappearing. I can do this both in the UIView class I have and in the UIViewController. Once these animations have been established, they do not need to be changed. Should I do this within the UIViewController or the UIView to stay MVC compliant?

The code is currently in my UIView as such:

```
- (IBAction)removeView
{
    NSLog(@"Remove");
    if (self.completionBlock != nil) {

        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y - self.superview.frame.size.height);
            self.alpha = 0; // also fade to transparent
        }completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {
             if (finished) {
                 [self removeFromSuperview];
             }
         }];

        self.completionBlock(YES);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your description, you can legitimately do them in either place because the animation does not depend on your application's model.  If, however, the animation depended on data from your model, then the controller should perform the animation because the controller sees the model data (but the view does not).

Answer (score 1):

The Views of the ViewController should be the ViewController's minons. You're going to have an easier time having the animation maths happen in the ViewController and have the ViewController update the View and this is the best practice according to MVC.

Also, I think it will be easier for you because you can make the logic based on an action as opposed to based on a class. I find that easier.